# vimeo api: play button for multiple videos

Tags: jquery, vimeo-api

I have different vimeo-iframe embeds and i want to have each embed has an own play-button.

I got the error: Uncaught TypeError: player.play is not a function

html:

```
<div class="video">
<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
<iframe class="vimeo" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/00000001?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=0000" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
<div class="btn">play</div>
</div>

<div class="video">
<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
<iframe class="vimeo" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/00000002?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=0000" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
<div class="btn">play</div>
</div>
...
```

js:
go through all iframes and initialize the player

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
    var nodelist = x.length;

    for (i = 0; i < nodelist; i++) {
        el = x[i];
        var player = new Vimeo.Player(x[i]);

        player.on('play', function () {
          console.log('played the video!');
        });

        player.on('ended', function () {
          console.log('ended the video!');
        });
      }
 });
```

js:
start one of many player on click

```
$(".btn").on('click', function() {
   var player = $(this).siblings("iframe")[0];
   console.log(player);
   player.play();

});
```

**Update:**

with this code I dont get an error, but how can i control which button will start which video? at the moment the first button is starting the last video

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
var nodelist = x.length;

for (i = 0; i < nodelist; i++) {
    el = x[i];
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(x[i]);
             
    document.querySelector('.play').addEventListener('click', function() {
          player.play();
        });  
  
    player.on('play', function () {
        console.log('played the video!');
     });
        
}
```

Comment: add the eventListener inside for loop. [example](https://codepen.io/andypillip/pen/BQBEVv)

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector('.play')` is indeed the first button no matter how many times you loop. Use `document.querySelectorAll(".play")[i]` instead.

```
var video_frame = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
var play_btn = document.querySelectorAll(".play");

var nodelist = video_frame.length;

for (i = 0; i < nodelist; i++) {
    el = video_frame[i];
    let player = new Vimeo.Player(x[i]);
             
    play_btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
          player.play();
        });  
  
    player.on('play', function () {
        console.log('played the video!');
     });
        
}
```